# Loading DATA into mySQL via text File

Tags: mysql, sql, database, dml, data-cleaning

I have created a table in mysql called person and am trying to load data into it using a text file. However, I have a restriction, I must load the data while checking if the SSN should be trimmed to an appropriate amount of characters. If the value is empty I also want to set SSN to NULL.
However, none of the commands I use want to work. For example, I have no idea why the line below isn't working.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/home/ugrad19/jflickin/cs482/PERSON.txt' INTO TABLE person
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(PIDM, FNAME, LNAME, @SSN, @DATE, GENDER)
SET SSN = LEFT(TRIM(@SSN), 8)             --this line messes it up. 
SET DOB = STR_TO_DATE(@DATE, '%m/%d/%Y');
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!!

Please note: I set the data type of SSN to Varchar(10). Please tell me if this is not the most appropriate datatype for this field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SET keyword appears once, multiple `col = expr` are separated by commas. For example:

```
SET SSN = LEFT(TRIM(@SSN), 9)            
  , DOB = STR_TO_DATE(@DATE, '%m/%d/%Y');
  ^
```

And social security numbers are generally **nine** digit characters, not eight.

Comment: I didn't know about the ',' and I assumed mysql started counting at 0. BUT THANKS it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET SSN = CASE WHEN @SSN = '' THEN NULL ELSE LEFT(TRIM(@SSN), 8) END
```

Comment: I get a syntax error with this, and with just SET SSN = LEFT(TRIM(@SSN), 8)